# Why don't Russians see cheating as something that must be eradicated?

Tags: ethics, cheating

This is a counterpart question to [How is cheating viewed in Western universities and why is it seen as such a big deal?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/195031/how-is-cheating-viewed-in-western-universities-and-why-is-it-seen-as-such-a-big)

To me it seems obvious that the direct goal of any exam or test is to check the knowledge of the student. The time and effort spent in preparing, taking, proctoring and checking the test is made useless if the student cheats as the whole purpose is destroyed. It would seem surprising that someone can take the opposite for granted.

However, from personal experience in work with students coming from Russian schools, I know what the OP in the other question means. When caught in plagiarism, Russians generally brush it off nonchalantly with a "ok ok, I copied that one". It is indeed seen by the majority of Russian students that cheating is a natural part of education.

Why don't Russians see it as a capital offence against the test? Why is cheating and plagiarism seen as a game or a challenge?

P.S. Of course: not all Russians.

Comment: I have a question about this idea. Is it Russians or is it a "feature" of Russian society that certain disadvantaged subgroups (ethnic/religious discrimination) has led to undesirable outcomes. I've known of some such groups that "stick together", helping one another on exams and such, even to the point of a secret "cough/sound language" to communicate during exams.

Comment: @Buffy, let me assure you, your assumption is wrong. Unfortunately, I'm Russian. And - taking the opportunity - I am apologizing for whoever reads it for all the evil we, Russians, have brought to the world. I have graduated from one of the best Russian universities with a relatively good score. I can justify firsthand to anyone that there is no "disadvantaged subgroups" aspect whatsoever to Russian culture of cheating. It was so utterly embarrassing to read the original cited question. It is with a great remorse and shame I confirm that it is who we, Russians, are.

Comment: my answer to the linked question in fact belongs here

Comment: I think that, at its core, this question is a sociological one rather than one for this forum.

Comment: The answers to the linked question adress this question as well. Voting to close as duplicate.

Comment: FWIW, in Poland (which, like Russia, belongs to the Eastern Europe) cheating is also tolerated - to the point that it is rarely, if ever, called directly "cheating" ("oszukiwanie"), but an euphemism is used instead ("ściaganie", literally "taking off"), both by students and teachers.

Answer (score 5):

The best answer is given [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/195058/125334), and I subscribe to every line of it. Here is one observation, which I find especially astute:

"On the other side of the iron curtain, cheating "the system" (be it your boss, the government or the grocery store) is really, really morally different from doing the same to people equal to you (friends, family, direct contractual partners or even an unknown person on the street). The former is acceptable and sometimes approved, the latter is not."

To this, I would only add that in much of the Eastern Europe there has always been a chasm between the officialdom and the people. The people never expected anything good from the "system". Hence the long-entrenched mindset: respect your fellow man, but feel free to cheat the authorities -- be it fiscal services, or the police, or a university, or just anything coming from the government. They are not your friends.